# Recursively search

Tags: python, recursion

I'm using a txt file as a "word search board" that has words scrambled through it. I am also using a list of words in another txt file that may or may not be located in the word board. Words are found in all directions, north ,south,east,west, NE,NW,SE,SW and reverse of those. The function that is searching through the board must be recursive. In my current `searchBoard()` , I am trying to just search through using the first letter of the word and then check the surroundings for the next letter after and so on. My recursive function is working the way I want it , any tips would be appreciated.

Example text file for board:

```
G J T P B A V K U V L V
M N Q H S G M N T C E E
Y H I J S G Q E N Y C W
G S K M G H C B M U T H
R A T V M N V D G V U T
E P G U E A B P W Q R T
T J C I D D R Q T E E C
U P C I S E N G B U O B
P S J C I V N F O U N N
M P R O J E C T R R A M
O H Q T P P D S H A P G
C O W U K Q E G I J M S
```

Other txt file with list of words:

```
COMPUTER 
SCRAM
COURSE
LECTURE
PROGRAMMING
PROJECT
SCIENCE
STUDENT
```

My code:

```
#Making the word file into a list
def getWords(wordList):
    fname = open(wordList,'r')
    lines = fname.read().split()

    return(lines)


#Making the puzzle file into a 2d list.
def buildBoard(puzzleBoard):

    fname = open(puzzleBoard,'r')
    boardList = []
    for line in fname:
        number_strings = line.split() 
        letters = [n for n in number_strings] 
        boardList.append(letters)

    fname.close()

    print(boardList[1][0])#row ,then col. Both start at 0s

    return(boardList)



#Recursively search board 
def searchBoard(pos,puzzleBoard,wordList):
    for word in wordList:
        firstLetter = word[:1]
        if puzzleBoard[pos[0]][pos[1]] == firstLetter:
           newPos = pos[0][0]
           searchBoard(newPos,puzzleBoard,wordList)

        #Checking above
        if puzzleBoard[pos[0]-1][pos[1]] == firstLetter:
          newPos = [pos[0]-1,pos[1]]  
          searchBoard(newPos,puzzleBoard,wordList)


def main():
    print("Welcome to the Word Search")
    print("For this, you will import two files: 1. The puzzle board, and 2. The word list.")
    puzzleBoard = input("What is the puzzle file you would like to import?: ")
    wordList = input("What is the word list file you would like to import?: ")

    puzzleBoard = buildBoard(puzzleBoard)    
    wordList = getWords(wordList)


    pos = [puzzleBoard[0][0]]
    searchBoard(pos,puzzleBoard,wordList)
main()
```

Error :

```
if puzzleBoard[pos[0]][pos[1]] == firstLetter:

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: not 100% sure if I got your code right, but pos is a string taken from puzzleBoard. You then try to lookup in boardlist which is a list by using your string pos. Try to use the lenght and height of the board as coordinates instead of pos.

Comment: That makes sense. I put rows= len(puzzleBoard),
    cols = len(puzzleBoard[0]),    
    pos = [puzzleBoard[rows][cols]]  , and now its giving me a list index out of range error.

Comment: the upper limit of the index of your list is rows-1 resp. col-1 since the index starts at 0.

Comment: Is there any reason you made `pos` into a list? `pos = [puzzleBoard[0][0]]`

Comment: No , @Ashafix made me realize what I was trying to do. More a long the lines of pos = (int(row),int(col)). And then use that as my coordinates in my recursive function maybe?

Comment: Recursion is a good idea, but the logic in `searchBoard` seems totally broken to me. Or maybe the function  just not finished?

Comment: @halo32008 beware with your recursion: when recursively calling `searchBoard()`, the search will always occur again to the first word (and the first letter of this word) of the list! And nowhere you check if you have the entire word.

Comment: @halo32008 You should consider adding an ending case, and adding/pass informations such as position in words/letters_from_a_word when recursively calling `searchBoard()`.

Comment: @robyschek Im beginning to think I need to re work another way I am going to recursively do this.

Comment: @vmnoteco  Im not sure if I understand what you mean by adding an ending case?

Comment: Site policy forbids vandalizing your own questions: that makes the question and answer useless for other people, and wastes the time of the people who helped to answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was a nice practice :)
I took your input puzzleboard and wrote a small function which recursively searches through the puzzleboard. First it tries to find the first letter of the word `text.find(word[0], pos)` and then changes the x,y coordinates for each direction by using floor and modulo divisions and looks for the next letter. If the next letter doesn't match, it tries the next direction until either the whole word is found, or the characters don't match or it leaves the boundaries of the puzzleboard.
All words but SCRAM are found in your puzzleboard.

```
text = """
G J T P B A V K U V L V
M N Q H S G M N T C E E
Y H I J S G Q E N Y C W
G S K M G H C B M U T H
R A T V M N V D G V U T
E P G U E A B P W Q R T
T J C I D D R Q T E E C
U P C I S E N G B U O B
P S J C I V N F O U N N
M P R O J E C T R R A M
O H Q T P P D S H A P G
C O W U K Q E G I J M S"""

#cleans the input puzzleBoard
text = text.replace(' ', '').strip()
#gets the width and height of the puzzleboard
width = len(text.splitlines()[0])
text = text.replace('\n', '')
height = len(text) / width

#a dictionary storing the human readable directions
directions={0:'NW',1:'N',2:'NE',3:'W',4:'',5:'E',6:'SW',7:'S',8:'SE'}

#tries to find a word in a text
#returns x,y of the first character and the orientation of the word
def find_word(text, word):
    pos = 0
    while pos != -1:
        pos = text.find(word[0], pos)
        if pos > -1:
            for ori in [0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8]:
                found = True
                i = 0
                x = pos % width
                y = pos // height

                while found:
                    i += 1
                    if i == len(word) and found:
                        return (pos % width, pos // height, directions[ori])
                    #moves x,y in the selected direction
                    x += ori % 3 - 1
                    y += ori // 3 - 1
                    if x < width and y < height and x > -1 and y > -1:
                        found = text[width * y + x] == word[i]
                    else:
                        found = False
            pos += 1
    #nothing found
    return(-1, -1, directions[4])
```

### Update

Solving the same problem, but by recursively calling the same function. The function returns the found word, the x,y position of the last letter and the orientation, i.e. one would need to go backwards to find the whole word.

```
def find_char(text, pos, word, ori):
    x = int(pos % width)
    y = int(pos // height)
    x += ori % 3 - 1
    y += ori // 3 - 1
    if text[pos] != word[0]:
        return None
    if len(word) == 1:
        return (x,y)
    if x < width and y < height and x > -1 and y > -1:
        pos = int(width * y + x)
        if text[pos] == word[1]:
            if len(word) > 1:
                resp = find_char(text, pos, word[1:], ori)
                if resp:
                    return resp
        else:
            return None

word_list = ['COMPUTER', 'SCRAM', 'COURSE', 'LECTURE', 'PROGRAMMING', 'PROJECT', 'SCIENCE', 'STUDENT']
for i in range(len(text)):
    for ori in [0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8]:
        for word in word_list:
            resp = find_char(text, i, word, ori)
            if resp:
                print(word, resp, ori)
```

Comment: Thank you for this response. But where is the recursive call?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I misread your question and updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for !

Answer (score 1):

If I print `pos` before passing it to `searchBoard()`, python prints me this :

```
['G']
```

You made pos a list with `pos = [puzzleBoard[0][0]]`, that is equal to `pos = ['G']`

So, when you try to access `puzzleBoard[pos[0]][pos[1]]` in your `searchBoard()` function, you try to access `puzzleBoard['G'][<nonsense>]`. Both indexes used are wrong.

Plus `pos` isn't the position, *but a list containing one of the characters from your double list*, and contains no more information (not even the position actually).

I suggest you to pass the possitions as integers to `searchBoard()` :

```
searchBoard(0, 0, puzzleBoard,wordList) # xpos and ypos being the first parameters for instance
```

or you could even do like this :

```
searchBoard((0, 0), puzzleBoard,wordList)
```

Here `pos` is a tuple that contains both indexes, but only these indexes, and no further information

**Edit** : as robyschek pointed out in comments, the first solution would be clearer!

## Other corrections if you use the tuple solution :

You'll have to change the new assignations to your `newPos` from :

```
newPos = pos[0][0]
```

into something like

```
newPos = (pos[0],pos[0])
```

I didn't understand how you planned to manage your indexes, but the main point is : **make it also a tuple**

Comment: Thank you, this clears up a lot. Ive decided to use what you said, but I just created the tuple in main. Now it is giving me an error: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison . At my first if statement in searchBoar() function.

Comment: `row, col` variant looks better than `tuple` as it reduces ugly nested indexing in searchBoard.

Comment: @robyschek indeed, plus names like xpos and ypos would be clearer.